# Steps after installing vCenter Server?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

### I'm working with:

- Two new ESX servers that I'm configuring
- A new Server 2008 R2 machine that I'm using for vCenter.

### I took the following steps:

- Installed the Hypervisor on the 2 ESX machines
- Checked their setup/connectivity (appears to be fine; can ping, etc.)
- Installed vCenter Server on the Win2k8R2 box. This included the install of a SQL Express database (we're a small shop)

  - **FYI, I changed some of the ports** (443 --> 8443, 80 -->8080, etc.)
- Installed vCenter Web Client Server on the Win2k8R2 box

### Problems

- **my vSphere Client on my Desktop fails to connect**. Part of this is that it asks me for a username and password, but I don't recall specifying one when I set up the install.

  - I receive the error "*vSphere Client could not connect to [machinename]. An unknown connection error occurred. (The request failed because of a connection failure. (Unable to connect to the remote server))"*
  - I have also tried to use local machine admin credentials, including the format *machinename\localuseracct*.
  - I have also tried using my domain credentials which are an admin for that box.
  - I have also checked and the service is running.
  - I also tried to connect via vSphere client locally installed on the server. It translates "localhost" to the correct name but gives the same error.
- **I cannot register the vCenter server from the vCenter Web Client Server**. I'm not sure if this is necessary, as they're both on the same machine, but it seems like the logical next step. I also receive a "failed to connect" error in this case as well.

  - FYI, both the vCenter server and the vCenter Web Client Server are installed on the same Win2k8R2 server.

What am I missing here? What is the best way to test in this case?

Comment: Have you had any training? Most courses cover these topics straight away and would prove an invaluable basis for evaluating and implementing VMware products.

Comment: you've checked that the windows firewall isn't blocking the connections, right?

Comment: @Chopper3, Unfortunately no, other than beginning to pour over the guides just now.

Comment: @RobM, Windows Firewall is turned off but we've got Symantec Endpoint Protection on there and that's a fair point. I'm in the process of getting the domain admins to check that out (nothing in the logs but can't be sure).

Comment: well if you've changed the default ports then those ports need to be unblocked...

Comment: Rob, as far as I can tell the only ports I've changed were on the server from 80 -->8080 and 443 --> 8443.  I can access those via a web browser on my client machine fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing. Answering here so that someone else may find an answer, but I'm not proud of this one. :)

The solution was a simple one: Due to changing the port, neglected to also append the port to the login box in the vSphere Client.

So, updating from [machinename] to [machinename]:8443 worked just fine.

Thanks to RobM for starting me down the path of realizing I'd overlooked something basic.

Comment: Don't be embarrassed, these sorts of errors can catch anyone!